# Dispatch TouchEvent to Listview after it's intercepted by parent

Tags: android, listview, touch-event

I have a layout which looks something like this:

[image: my layout]

Inside the ViewPager are a number of Fragments, of which each holds a ListView.

Now I want to do this:

By scrolling down, the ListView mustn't scroll. Instead the header has to be transformed so it looks like a native ActionBar.

I'm doing this by intercepting the TouchEvent in the root layout of my activity.
I have overwritten the onInterceptTouchEvent() method of my parent layout and check if a TouchEvent should be intercepted or not, by retrieving the current visible ListView and check if the firstVisibleItem is the first and it's completely visible. 
If the TouchEvent should be intercepted, my custom OnGesutreListener's onScroll() method is called. So the "animation" progress depends on the scroll offset.

All that works really fine. **But now here's my problem**:

The transformation is ready and the user still scrolls down. As a user i would expect the ListView to scroll down. But the TouchEvent isn't dispatched to the ListView because it's still intercepted by the parent layout. Only after moving the finger up and down again onInterceptTouchEvent is called again (now the parent layout hasn't to intercept) and the list is scrollable.

I tried a few things but they didn't work out for me:

- I tried to call my listView's onTouchEvent manually in the
  onTouchEvent() method of my parent's layout - noting happens
- I tried to call my listView's onTouchEvent manually in my onScroll method,
  also this didn't worked out.

Maybe some of you have a clue how to work this out.

Thanks a lot and greetz!

Comment: I would like to do what you have done! Do you have an example how do you override the OnIntercetpTouchEvent() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try getting the x position moved by the finger in the parent onTouchEvent and then using

```
listView.smoothScrollByOffset(int offset);
```

To scroll the list view?

Edit: Based on feedback it should be:

```
smoothScrollBy((int) distanceY, 1);
```

Comment: uuuh... that sounds promissing! I'm trying this out right now and let you know it it works :)

Comment: you'r answer didn't do the job. But it helped me a lot: Calling the ListView's smoothScrollBy((int) distanceY, 1) works fine! If you edit your answer I accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MungoRae's answer I could figure it out (please give him an upvote!)

```
listView.smoothScrollBy(int offset, int durationInMillis)
```

this works fine for me. The offset is the scrolled distanceY and the duration is set to 1 msec

Answer (score 1):

You can use **View.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()**. It will enable and disable the ability of a view to intercept touch event.

set **requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)** on the parent layout while touching , it will enable the listview to handle the touch event.